# Cannot install Jupyter with python 3

Tags: jupyter

While trying to install Jupyter, I got the following error:

```
jupyter@lamp-nlu-java:~$ sudo pip3 install jupyter
Downloading/unpacking jupyter
Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking notebook (from jupyter)
Downloading notebook-5.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB): 6.9MB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking ipywidgets (from jupyter)
Downloading ipywidgets-6.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46kB): 46kB downloaded
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2482, in _dep_map
return self.__dep_map
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2344, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map
```

What does it mean? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

1) Try to upgrade pip and then try to install jupyter.

2) The other best way to get jupyter notebook is to install Anaconda. Anaconda has jupyter and many other packages which you can make use of.